# Why is MongoDB (with SSL) asking for the .pem passphrase multiple times?

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I'm starting MongoDB with the following command (which I'll eventually add to a script):

```
mongod --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile ./certs/myCertAndKey.pem
```

After which, mongo will prompt:

> Enter PEM passphrase

Which is fine, but upon entering the correct passphrase it will ask again. And again.

**Mongo asks for the PEM password FIVE times in a row!**
I know I'm entering the password correctly because if I enter it wrong just once, I'll get a failure message.

Is this normal? Is there a way to simplify this other than removing the password from the pem file?

My end goal is to have my spring boot application start up the local MongoDB with SSL if it isn't already running, but asking for the password 5 times is ridiculous.

Version info:

- MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
- git version: 888390515874a9debd1b6c5d36559ca86b44babd
- OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
- allocator: system
- modules: none
- build environment:

  - distarch: x86_64
  - target_arch: x86_64

Comment: Did you try to specify PEMKeyPassword  option while starting mongod ?

Comment: Thank you, I had not tried that! While that does prevent mongo from asking for the password multiple times it also leaves the password for the private key in the terminal history.

Comment: Adding it as an answer for further reference, it would be appreciated if you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to disable promption of passphrase by specifying [PEMKeyPassword](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.ssl.PEMKeyPassword)

To start mongod with a configuration file, you can use below command:

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

And you need to specify **PEMKeyPassword** in the below structure:

```
net:
   port: <int>
   bindIp: <string>
   maxIncomingConnections: <int>
   wireObjectCheck: <boolean>
   ipv6: <boolean>
   unixDomainSocket:
      enabled: <boolean>
      pathPrefix: <string>
      filePermissions: <int>
   http:
      enabled: <boolean>
      JSONPEnabled: <boolean>
      RESTInterfaceEnabled: <boolean>
   ssl:
      sslOnNormalPorts: <boolean>  # deprecated since 2.6
      mode: <string>
      PEMKeyFile: <string>
      PEMKeyPassword: <string>
      clusterFile: <string>
      clusterPassword: <string>
      CAFile: <string>
      CRLFile: <string>
      allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: <boolean>
      allowInvalidCertificates: <boolean>
      allowInvalidHostnames: <boolean>
      disabledProtocols: <string>
      FIPSMode: <boolean>
   compression:
      compressors: <string>
```

Comment: This does stop it from asking for the password multiple times, however leaving the password for your private key in the terminal history is not the best practice.

I'll give this question a day to hopefully get a more ideal solution before accepting this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually you should use a configuration file to start mongod instance, so that your password wont be in terminal history.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to go with configuration file. Add that to your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Added @Allen :)

Comment: Thanks for your help!